# zip Folder without using getRealPath

Tags: php

I'm trying to make zip file from a folder inside my localhost server which is my computer with windows 7 OS to a host .The problem is with using getRealPath for making the zip file the zip file content would be like this "D:\xampp\htdocs\mobl\admin\downloads" but I don't want those folders inside my zip file.
How should I make zip file without those folders and just the target folder ?

this is the code I'm using to zip the folder

```
enter code here
```

$zip = new ZipArchive;

```
$zip->open('downloads/'.$zipname,ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Initialize empty "delete list"
$filesToDelete = array();

// Create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

foreach($files as $name => $file) {
    // Get real path for current file
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();

    // Add current file to archive
    $zip->addFile($filePath);
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Thanks

Comment: check if $filePath is directory, when not, add file

Comment: Look at the parameter "localName" of ZipArchive::addFile() : http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: @donald123 there is a folder which has other folders and files inside it.I'm trying to zip the whole folder with contents.

Comment: @slaur4 could you tell me how to use it?

Comment: $zip->addFile($filePath, $file->getBaseName())